# can't set variable in JavaScript based on json id from php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, getjson, json

I have a simple array from a php file (the reason for not using a json file is cause this info comes from a mysql database)

```
$array[0] = array('id' => 1,'price' => '325');
$array[1] = array('id' => 2,'price' => '486');      
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

and it echos as:

```
[{"id":1,"price":"325"},{"id":2,"price":"486"}]
```

now what I want to do is take the id and add it to a variable called counterval so that JavaScript will read it as

```
counterval1 = 325;
counterval2 = 486;
```

but I can't seem to get it to read that way. Here is the script at the current moment.

```
$.getJSON('test.php',function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i) {
    counterval + data[i].id = data[i].price;
    console.log (counterval2);
});
    $('#results').html(counterval2);    
});
var counterval1 = 0;
var counterval2 = 0;
```

any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use an array? `counterval[data[i].id]`?

Comment: Please update your title and tags to JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't do that... but you can do this...

```
var counterval = [];

$.getJSON('test.php',function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i) {
         counterval[data[i].id] = data[i].price;
         console.log (counterval[2]);
    });
    $('#results').html(counterval[2]);    
});
counterval[1] = 0;
counterval[2] = 0;
```

Comment: hmm... console.log seems to say an error of 'unexpected token' but I see what your getting at.

Comment: maybe you don't have a `2` in there?

Comment: no, kept giving me the same error, I think it was having problems with the var counterval[1] = 0;

Comment: ahh... how about changing `var counterval = [];` to `var counterval = {};`

Comment: hmm.. nope same output. I even tried copy pasting from your script.

Comment: fixed it, it was as I thought. I removed the var at the bottem and the script executed as It should. Thank you so much for all your help

Answer (score 2):

See my comment on your post. If you really want the vars to look like you explained:

```
eval("counterval" + data[i].id + " = data[i]..price");
alert(counterval1);
```

Comment: This is correct, but it does what he wants. I wouldn't recommend it though.

Comment: This does work very well with what I'm wanting, I would like to know why Imperative you say you would not recommend it?

Comment: Read through this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Comment: ah I see, what might be a safer route? rather then using eval.